# Social Media icons for specific image or post rather than entire site

Tags: button, share, blogs

I've been searching for a way to add sharing icons to specific posts or images on a website. I'm setting up a blog-type site and I've been able to place sharing icons for social media that when clicked share the blog as a whole but I'd like to find a way to put them on individual posts so that users can share the post rather than the whole site. A good example is how blogger handles the sharing for posts.

The site I'm working on is here:
blog.crittersandgods.com

FYI, the posts are in individual divs with the same class, all nested in one outer div.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try social sharing service directly from 3rd aprty provider which provide the code to copy paste and you are good to go......if you are using CMS then it is very easy to do too. Try sharethis, loginradius and others